# I am having an issue with this Java constructor program

Tags: java

Here' the Class :

```
public class Rectangle { 

private double lenght ;
private double width ;
public String name ;

public Rectangle (double len, double w, String n)

{
    lenght = len;
     width = w;
     name = n;
}

 public double getLenght()
 {
    return  lenght ;
 }

 public double getWidth ()
 {
     return width ;
 }

 public String getName() 
 {
     return name ;
 }

 public double getArea ()
 {
     return lenght * width  ;
 }
```

}

And here' s my constructor:

```
public class roomConstructor {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    double roomLenght, roomWidht,  totalArea;
    String roomName;

    Rectangle kitchen, bedroom, den;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("What is the name of your kitchen? " );
    roomName = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is the lenght of the kitchen ? " );
    roomLenght = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("What is the widht of the kitchen ? ");
    roomWidht =keyboard.nextDouble();
    kitchen = new Rectangle(roomLenght, roomWidht, roomName );

    System.out.println("What is the name of your bedroom? " );
    roomName = keyboard.nextLine();
    keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is the lenght of the bedroom ? ");
    roomLenght = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("What is your bedroom withd ? ");
    roomWidht = keyboard.nextDouble();
    bedroom = new Rectangle(roomLenght,roomWidht, roomName );

    System.out.println("What is the name of your den? " );
    roomName = keyboard.nextLine();
    keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println(" What is the lenght of your den ? ");
    roomLenght =keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("What is the widht of your den ? ");
    roomWidht =keyboard.nextDouble();
    den = new Rectangle ( roomLenght, roomWidht,roomName);

    totalArea = kitchen.getArea() + bedroom.getArea() + den.getArea();

    System.out.println(" The total area of your room is : " + totalArea);
    System.out.println(" The name of your kitchen is : " + kitchen.getName());
    System.out.println(" The name of your kitchen is : " + bedroom.getName());
    System.out.println("The name of your bedroom is : " + den.getName());
    System.out.println("The lenght of the kitchen is : " + bedroom.getLenght());


}
```

}

When I try to get the bedroom or den name it's missing the all name answer I get is the kitchen then there are 2 blank answers 5lmissing name for bedroom and den) What should I do please ? Thanks for your help

Comment: Just a note: your code is full of typos. It's `width` and `length`. Not `widht` and `lenght`. You're alwo abusing the term "constructor", and not respecting the Java naming conventions.

Comment: I look at the other question and did not fully understood with my question is so duplicate. I am still having the same issue. Thanks for the BIG help in learning java. God the world is soooooooooo rude bad.

Answer (score 1):

`Keyboard.nextDouble()` does not consume the newLine character. Call `Keyboard.nextLine()` after each call to `Keyboard.nextDouble()`.

This is throwing off your data storage in the constructors because you're mismatching input when not consuming the `\n` character

Comment: I have used keyboard.nexLine () because I got 2 questions on the same time :What is the name of your bedroom? " What is the lenght of the bedroom ? so that fixed the issue

Comment: `Double.parseDouble(keyboard.nextLine())` is a better option.

Comment: Andrew thanks it was helpful but I still get the bedroom name missing . Here's the new code :System.out.println("What is the name of your bedroom? " );
  roomName = keyboard.nextLine();
  keyboard.nextLine();
  System.out.println("What is the lenght of the bedroom ? ");
  roomLenght = keyboard.nextDouble();
  System.out.println("What is your bedroom withd ? ");
  roomWidht = keyboard.nextDouble();
  keyboard.nextLine();
  bedroom = new Rectangle(roomLenght,roomWidht, roomName )

Comment: @Freddy53 you only need to consume the newline character if you invoke any other method than keyboard.nextLine()

Comment: Understood Andrew but in this example if I don't add keyboard.nextLine() under roomName = keyboard.nextLine(); the program will ask both questions on the same times : What is the name of your bedroom?What is the lenght of the bedroom ?

Comment: Thanks Andrew I finally got it working . Thanks for your help again , I was about to give up Java , spent the entire day trying to figure what was wrong with the code.

Comment: you got it @Freddy53